# Slider for outsystems using jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, outsystems

I need a slider component for Outsystems application where-in I have three values low, medium and high. (Lets say low-> 0, medium->5, high->10)
It should be possible for a user to place the slider indicator on any of these values.

Any hints?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just in need for a slider that ables you to fill it with an array of ranges, you can just go for jquery UI one :

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps

Great funcitionnalities and support.

EDIT : for color evolving, you could make a div for the tooltip with a color background, that you will change depending on the value selected. Your code would look like something like this :

```
(if val == 1){handle.css('color','red');}
else if(val == 5){handle.css('color','yellow')} 
else if (val == 10) {handle.css('color','green')}
```

Comment: @ jonBreizh - Thanks for your quick concern, but I need a slider which will change its color when then value changes. For low -> red, for high -> green, for medium -> yellow. Any Hints ?

Comment: @ GrowWithWPF : You mean the actual color of the slider handle ?